# Can I upload file with Java Spring when Chrome and Safari return fakepath

Tags: java, jquery, spring, file-upload

Today I implemented uploading function in J2EE/Spring. But when I choose file to upload, it returns C:/fakepath/... in Chrome and Safari.

So I want to ask, Can I upload these files normally or I will get some errors during uploading process because of fakepath.

Comment: you shouldn't be working with the client file path, you should be reading the file contents and from there do whatever you want to with it.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am newbie in Java uploading file, but I don't understand, how can Java code read file contents if Chrome or Safari return fakepath, not real path of client

Comment: Java can read the file contents, but the path is not accesible for security(avoiding threads). The file contents are posted to the server, and the path is tweaked for this security improvement that I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks very much Eric. Now I can upload document successfully. Everything are clear now

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you were able to find a workaround.